# Axios syntax trouble, using dynamic calls and getting a response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have never used this style of Axios call and unfortunately, it's the only one the API works with and it's the only API I can find that has the right data.
When I make the call I get undefined answers and I'm not sure how to reformat the axios call so that it works. As well as I need to pass in custom parameters to the call at some point but I'm not sure how to access them in the ReactJS file.

Any help would be great!

API FILE

```
const axios = require("axios");

const country = "US";
const currency = "USD";
const locale = "en-US";
const originplace = "SFO-sky";
const destinationplace = "JFK-sky";
const outboundpartialdate = "anytime"; // “yyyy-mm-dd”

axios({
  "method": "GET",
  "url": "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/" + country + "/" + currency + "/" + locale + "/" + originplace + "/" + destinationplace + "/" + outboundpartialdate,
  // "url": "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/SFO-sky/JFK-sky/anytime",
  // "url": "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/any/any/anytime",
  // "url": "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/"+originplace+"/JFK-sky/anytime",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "",
    "useQueryString": true
  }, "params": {
    "inboundpartialdate": "2019-12-01",
  }
})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data); //Logs the correct output
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

REACTJS FILE

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import flightAPI from "../utils/flightAPI";
import { Col, Row, Container } from "../components/Grid";
import SiteNav from "../components/SiteNav";
import FlightsCard from "../components/FlightsCard";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import "./style.css"

function Home() {

    // Setting our component's initial state
    const [flights, setFlights] = useState([])

    // Load all states and store them with setStates
    useEffect(() => {
        loadFlights()
    }, [])

    // Loads all states and sets them to states
    function loadFlights() {


        setFlights(flightAPI),
            console.log("This is the response: "), // Logs {}
            console.log(flightAPI),
            console.log("This is the current state: "), // Logs []
            console.log(flights)

    };


    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col size="md-12">
                        <SiteNav />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col size="md-12">
                        <h1 id="hotflights">Hot Flights</h1>
                        <FlightsCard />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    {flights && flights.map(function (flight, i) {
                        return (

                            <Col size="3">
                                <FlightsCard/>
                            </Col>
                        )
                    })}
                </Row>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Footer />
            </Container >
        </div >
    );
}
export default Home;
```

I changed the API call to look like:

```
export default {
  getFlightData: function () {
    return (
      fetch("https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/browsequotes/v1.0/US/USD/en-US/MSP-sky/JFK-sky/anytime?inboundpartialdate=anytime", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
          "x-rapidapi-key": ""
        }
      })
        .then((response) => {
          response.json();
        })
    )
  }
}
```

This still gives undefined as the return.

Comment: Is that the entire API file? Because you aren't exporting anything. That makes `flightAPI` in your React file `undefined`. In addition, setting state is async, so even if you fix that, `console.log(flights)` will log the previous value, not the new value. (also, that axios call can definitely be replaced with an appropriate fetch call, you just need to make sure that it produces the same request, and you shouldn't post private API keys on here)

Comment: @ChrisG I'll try exporting a function and I am aware of the async but even on a secondary refresh of the page, it won't display anything. I also deleted the API thanks I'm still a complete noob.

Comment: Here's how to use the exported function: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-dew-k99m3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I refactored it so the call looks the same as the example you provided but I still get a state of undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by "this style of Axios call"? What's special about how you are using Axios here?

Comment: @jarmod So I meant that passing into the headers. I tried implementing the suggestion above to use fetch tho and the API call has been changed to the one at the bottom of the post. Although I still can't get that to pass into the state correctly. It still logs as undefined...

Comment: If you've changed your code, please put (only) relevant parts into the question. Also what exactly is `undefined`? Did you also look at `UserAPI.js` from the sandbox to see how to properly export?